# Python comparing unordered lists where the elements in one list has prefixed text

Tags: python

How to do a comparison between two lists in python to find items in List A that don't also appear in List B but where the format/layout of the items in each list vary slightly with one list having either a prefix/affix on each item?

I thought it would be a simple [ List A - List B ] but this seems to search for literal 1 to 1 matches which in this case that logic means no item in List A matches a item in List B.

Example:
List A with the text prefixed on items:

```
[ 'foo/BAR', 'foo/XYZ', 'foo/ABC', 'foo/123' ]
```

And List B where items don't include the prefix:

```
[ 'ABC', 'ZYX', '123', 'BAR' ]
```

Is the way to do this to just format List A and drop the prefix before doing any comparisons?
Or is there a method of comparing items without needing to do formatting?

Comment: What's your expected output? What have you already tried? Also are you aware that these are lists, not sets?

Comment: Try `{i for i in a if i.split('/')[1] not in b}`

Comment: Yes I am referring to comparing lists not comparing sets.
I am new to python and not 100% across all the differences in the data types.

From the example lists shown above the item without match in both is 'foo/XYZ'
The intended output is a list of items from Set A that don't have any match in Set B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set_a = {'foo/BAR', 'foo/XYZ', 'foo/ABC', 'foo/123'}
set_b = {'ABC', 'ZYX', '123', 'BAR'}

final_set_a = {item for x in set_a for item in set_b if x in item}
final_set_b = {item for x in set_b for item in set_a if x in item}

if final_set_b:
    print(set_a ^ final_set_b)
elif final_set_a:
    print(set_b ^ final_set_a)
```

Comment: I've edited the original post to indicate that this is working with lists not sets.
Hence this method is invalid.

Comment: It doesn't allowed to use sets at all? Or just original data in list?

Comment: I think the lists could be converted to sets but I am not sure if anything would break. I would need to test that.

Comment: You just need in to make little changes, like:
print(set(set_a) ^ final_set_b)

or
print(set(set_b) ^ final_set_b)

on case if set_a and set_b are lists.

Comment: Yes it was easy to get working. It was just a matter of initializing the variables as sets using set_a = set() and then adding data to it. I presume this should also be faster when comparing as the documentation seems to suggest sets > lists for speed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
set_a = [ 'foo/BAR', 'foo/XYZ', 'foo/ABC', 'foo/123' ]

set_b = [ 'ABC', 'ZYX', '123', 'BAR' ]

def parse_from_a(x):
    if '/' in x:
        return x.split('/')[1]
    # add more parsing logic here
    return x

fixed_set_a = {parse_from_a(x) for x in set_a}
fixed_set_b = set(set_b)

print(fixed_set_a - fixed_set_b)
```

it prints the single item set:

> {'XYZ'}

Comment: This assumes the prefix is static with {x[4:] for x in set_a}
The prefix can be completely random in length and sometimes may not appear at all depending on the data source.

Comment: I edited my response to now use a parsing function that you can extend as needed, and modified my parsing function to handle the case of N length prefix or a missing prefix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want `['foo/XYZ']`. You could iterate over A, split on the slash, and check if the second part is in B.

```
a = ['foo/BAR', 'foo/XYZ', 'foo/ABC', 'foo/123']
b = ['ABC', 'ZYX', '123', 'BAR']

out = []
for s in a:
    prefix, word = s.split('/')
    if word not in b:
        out.append(s)
print(out)  # -> ['foo/XYZ']
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
out = [s for s in a if s.split('/')[1] not in b]
print(out)  # -> ['foo/XYZ']
```

Comment: I thought of using split but it's not ideal since I presume it will effect results in the event that when Set A is generated it may not contain the prefix.
And it is not always guaranteed there will be a prefix depending on the source data-set.

Comment: @Riordan Then you just need a more complex splitting function. Either way filtering A will look the same.

Comment: This works well for the use case here after testing and I should be able to just add some logic to skip doing a split if there is no '/' found in list A